# Unable to use my method with Slick library

Tags: java

So I made a java game with jumping some time ago and I used this method for all the moving:

```
double height = 0, speed = 4;
    public static final double gravity = 9.81;
    double x = 25;
    int a;
    int y = (int) (500-(height*100));
    boolean left = false, right = false, up = false;

public void the_jump() {
        long previous = 0, start = 0;
        while(true){
            start = System.nanoTime();
            if(previous != 0 && up){
                double delta = start - previous;
                height = (height + (delta/1000000000) * speed);        
                speed -= (delta/1000000000)  * gravity;
                y = (int) (500-(height * 100));
            }  
            if(left){
                x-= 3;
            }    
            if(right){
                x+= 3;
            }    
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(height < 0){
                height = 0;
                speed = 4; 
                up = false;
            }      
            previous = start;
        }
    }
```

Now It was okay when I did it all with just JComponents and such, but now when I want to implement it in a Slick enviroment, it fails.

The problem is in the `while(true){}` loop. If I change it against `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` loop, then moving left and right will work. But this will not work for the jumping. I could increase the `i < 1 to i < 5` and then the jump will work, but at the cost of a lot of performance.

So how would people implement this in slick? Right now I am calling the `the_jump();` out in my `public void update(GameContainer gc, int t) throws SlickException` method, and if I use the while loop, the game will crash.

Comment: Can ofcourse provide more info if needed.

Comment: "if I use the while loop, the game will crash" - you should probably provide exception stack traces, and indicate which line(s) they are thrown from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick already loop on `update(GameContainer gc, int delta)`, you have to put all the code located in your `while` loop into the `update` method.
Moreover, you get the delta time between two update as parameter, and so not have to calculate it.

Feel free to ask me more question ;)

Off Topic, do you know if Slick2d is still maintain ? I switch to [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) a few month ago, and I really advice you to test it, it's soooo fun :)

Comment: I actually have not head of libGDX before, I will give it a shot :) On topic, will see if the solution works.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)